# No file was uploaded error Zend framework 3 validation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-validate, zend-inputfilter

I want use `Callback` validation but `continue_if_empty` not working for `File`, it’s returning `No file was uploaded` error. But everything working for `Input` and `Select`. I need help with this.

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'images',
    'required' => false,
    'allow_empty' => true,
    'continue_if_empty' => true,
    'type' => FileInput::class,
    'filters' => [
        [
            'name' => Rename::class,
            'options' => [
                'target' => '/var/www/project/public/website/content/tmp/image_' . md5(time()),
                'randomize' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'validators' => [
        [
            'name' => Callback::class,
            'options' => [
                'callback' => [$this, 'imageValidator'],
            ],
        ],
     ],
]);


public function imageValidator($value, $context)
{
     dd($context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This helped me to solve "No file was uploaded" error.*

Include this line in your view template (.phtml) before you open form tag:

> $form->prepare()

Full Example:

```
<!-- File: upload-form.phtml -->
<?php
    $form->prepare(); // The correct enctype is set here
    $fileElement = $form->get('image-file');
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>

    <div class="form-element">
        <?= $this->formLabel($fileElement) ?>
        <?= $this->formFile($fileElement) ?>
        <?= $this->formElementErrors($fileElement) ?>
    </div>

    <button>Submit</button>

<?= $this->form()->closeTag() ?>
```

Source: https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-form/file-upload/